# Change Default Icon to MarkerWithLabel

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have beenn searching a lot about the way to show dynamic text with a marker using google maps api V3. Finally I found a simple solution using the MarkerWithLabel.
     Full documentation following the link

[link](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/trunk/markerwithlabel/src/markerwithlabel.js?r=131)

The problem i have now is that  i want to change the default icon of the markerwithlabel
or if that is not possible just do not show it.

I really would like to know if anyone had the same problem Cose i fail to finf anything related on thje web

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think all you have to do is pass the 'icon' parameter to your constructor, like this: MarkerWithLabel extends Marker, it says.

```
x = new MarkerWithLabel({
  icon: 'http://www.mysite.com/myimage.png'
});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions